# ヘルプセンターの内容が古い：アカウントのマージ

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語, ヘルプ

[日本語版のヘルプセンター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)では最初の段落が

> 1 つに合わせたいアカウントが 2 件ある場合は、各プロフィールの [自分について] セクションを「merge keep」 (マージして保存) および「merge delete」 (マージして削除) と編集してから[お問い合わせ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/contact)ください。マージしたい 2 つのプロフィールへのリンクを提示してください。「merge delete」と指定したものを「merge keep」と指定したものにマージします。

となっていますが、現在の[英語版](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)では以下のように変更されています。

> If you have two accounts that you would like to join together, please sign into either account, visit the [contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) and select ‘I need to merge user profiles’. After you contact us, the Stack Exchange Team will reach out to verify that you own both accounts. If we can confirm your ownership, we will initiate a merge.

翻訳案：

> 2つのアカウントを統合したい場合は、どちらかのアカウントでログインした状態で[お問い合わせフォーム](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/contact)にアクセスし、「ユーザー プロフィールをマージする必要があります」を選択してください。両方のアカウントの所有者があなたであることを Stack Exchange チームで確認したのちに、アカウントのマージが行われます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

適用しました。確認宜しくお願いします。

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts